# Center a table and align right a div

Tags: html, css

I'm not having much luck in centering the pageLinks table and right align the goToPage div within the pagingDiv div.  I needs these two element positioned at the same vertical level.  any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="pagingDiv" style="border:1px solid black; width:100%;">
    <table id="pageLinks" style="border:1px solid black; margin:auto;" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#first" title="Click to go to first page.">1</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#first" title="Click to go to second page.">2</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>                  
    <div id="goToPage" style="float:right"> &nbsp; Page 3 of 42 | Page#: <input style="height:14px;width:21px;" /> <a href="#go">GO</a></div>                  
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/63uKv/

Comment: The code work except that it is not positioning those two elements at the same line (veritically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the goToPage div before the table in your HTML:

```
<div id="pagingDiv" style="border:1px solid black; width:100%;">
    <div id="goToPage" style="float:right">&nbsp; Page 3 of 42 | Page#:
        <input style="height:14px;width:21px;" /> <a href="#go">GO</a>
    </div>
    <table id="pageLinks" style="border:1px solid black; margin:auto;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <a href="#first" title="Click to go to first page.">1</a>

                </td>
                <td> <a href="#first" title="Click to go to second page.">2</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Z6wTc/)**

Comment: Can't believe I spent two hours for this.  I would have never think of trying that.  Thank you.

Comment: I just realized that the table is actually not positioned at the center of pagingDiv.  Its off centered by the link of goToPage.