# Auto expand outer table to prevent overlay due to position: absolute

Tags: html, css

This is a continuation of previously posted question: [Center a table and align right a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344159/center-a-table-and-align-right-a-div).  On this previous question, j08691 provided a perfect solution to center a table and right align a div.  But now I've encontered problem with the pageDiv and PageLinks elements overlay each other if I put them in a outer table.  See this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/hockchailim/uECFg/4/.  Is there a way to auto expand the outer table to prevent such overlay?

```
<table id="outerTable" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="pagingDiv" style="width:100%;">
                <div id="goToPage" style="float:right">&nbsp; Page 3 of 42 | Page#:
                    <input style="height:14px;width:21px;" /> <a href="#go">GO</a>

                </div>
                <table id="pageLinks" style="margin:auto;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <a href="#first" title="Click to go to first page.">1</a>
                            </td>
                            <td> <a href="#first" title="Click to go to second page.">2</a>
                            </td>
                            <td> <a href="#first" title="Click to go to second page.">3</a>
                            </td>
                            <td> <a href="#first" title="Click to go to second page.">4</a>
                            </td>
                            <td> <a href="#first" title="Click to go to second page.">5</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            This is too short,  <br/> 
            it caused goToPage and pageLinks <br/>
            on previous cell is overlaying each other
        </td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>                
</table>
```

Comment: Please draw what you need, as it's not clear. Do you want one below the other? next to each other? aligned left / right?

Comment: not sure how to draw this.  Can you try go to the jsfiddle link and change the outer table 2nd row text to be something really long?  You should see that the pageDiv will be postion at the center of the outer table and pageLinks on the right.  That is what I wanted.  The problem ocurr when the 2nd row text is too short.  When this happen, it causes the pageDiv and pageLinks to overlay each other.  When this happen, I would like the outer table to auto expand to the length where they won't overlay.

Comment: You've removed `#goToPage` from the page flow, so things won't wrap. If your pagination is of a fixed size (you're only going to give links to 5 pages, and your page # text doesn't change), giving `#pagingDiv` an appropriate `min-width` would be the simplest way to make things "auto-expand".

Comment: all the data include pagingDiv and pageLinks are dynamic.  Length will vary.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after? I removed the positioning from the Div's

```
#pagingDiv {

}
#goToPage {

    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uECFg/6/

Comment: Unfortunately, removing position:absolute; from goToPage will cause the pagingDiv to no longer position at the center of the outerTable.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it for you? I removed some styling

```
#goToPage {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uECFg/9/[][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/uECFg/9/ <------ UPDATE

Comment: Unfortunately, removing position:absolute; from goToPage will cause the pagingDiv to no longer position at the center of the outerTable (You should see what I mean if you change the outer table 2nd row text to be something really long).  Please note that all the data, including pagingDiv and pageLinks, are dynamically created.  So, they will vary in size.

Comment: same problem.  PagingDiv no longer postion at the center of outer table

Comment: Are you changing just css or using the whole fiddle? because I've changed html as well

Comment: I did add <table id="pageLinks" align="center">

Comment: Sorry, I mean pagingDiv no longer float right and it is no longer on the same line as pageLinks.  See http://jsfiddle.net/hockchailim/uECFg/12/